# Animation does not work

Tags: android, android-animation, android-fragmentactivity

Had a little problem. My animation does not work. I don't get any kind of errors. Simply my animation does not work.

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());
    }

    public static class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class Tab2Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout, container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class Tab3Fragment extends Fragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (container == null) {
                return null;
            }
            return (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag3_layout, container, false);
        }
    }

    public static class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }

    public static class ZoomOutPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {
        private static final float MIN_SCALE = 0.85f;
        private static final float MIN_ALPHA = 0.5f;

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {
            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();
            int pageHeight = view.getHeight();

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
//              view.setAlpha(0);
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                // Modify the default slide transition to shrink the page as well
                float scaleFactor = Math.max(MIN_SCALE, 1 - Math.abs(position));
                float vertMargin = pageHeight * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                float horzMargin = pageWidth * (1 - scaleFactor) / 2;
                if (position < 0) {
//                  view.setTranslationX(horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, horzMargin - vertMargin / 2);
                } else {
//                  view.setTranslationX(-horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
                    ViewHelper.setTranslationX(view, -horzMargin + vertMargin / 2);
                }

                // Scale the page down (between MIN_SCALE and 1)
//              view.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
//              view.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
                ViewHelper.setScaleX(view, scaleFactor);
                ViewHelper.setScaleY(view, scaleFactor);

                // Fade the page relative to its size.
//              view.setAlpha(MIN_ALPHA +
//                      (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
//                      (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, MIN_ALPHA +
                        (scaleFactor - MIN_SCALE) /
                        (1 - MIN_SCALE) * (1 - MIN_ALPHA));

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
//              view.setAlpha(0);
                ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Every thing else is working fine. I want to implement [this.](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#zoom-out) please help me.

Before i implemented without using NineOldroids. But even after implementing this, it didn't work.

Comment: Where is the code for the animation?

Comment: check this ZoomOutPageTransformer class.

Comment: Please make a comment if you think my code is having any kind of technical flaws rather than simply making a vote down. It will help me to correct and improve my coding standards. Anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did not work in emulator with android 2.2 platform, but when i checked in my Phone Sony Xperia Tipo Dual having ICS as platform, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I also have that problem check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018634/issue-using-viewpager-and-pagetransformer-with-android-api-11?answertab=active#tab-top). Using nineoldandroid should work but PageTransform is ignored in pre 11 (Heneycomb) although it's in the support library. I'm thinking of moving to view flipper just to do the animation. But i'm still searching for another way.

EDIT: CHeck out my answer in that Question to see how i resolved the issue. I basicly copied the viewpager class and removed the if statement that checked the SDK version in setPageTransformer